# Find mode of list of list

Tags: python

I want to find mode from list of list.
So basically there will be one list which contains list of list.

- also, in every list the order doesn't matter. So `["red", "blue"] == ["blue", "red"]`
- Plus, if this list contains more than one mode, I want all of them. *I'll concatenate all the mode list and make it as a single list (also will remove duplicates, (like creating a set out of this or think of it as a union of all mode list))*
- In the example given below, list `["red", "blue", "green"]` occurs most frequently, so I want to print that.

Here is an example list :

```py
my_list = [
    ["red", "blue", "blue"],
    ["red"],
    ["blue","yellow"],
    ["green","yellow"],
    ["pink"],
    ["red", "blue", "blue"],
    ["red", "green", "red"], 
    ["red", "yellow", "red"],
    ["green", "red", "blue"],   # +1
    ["blue", "green", "red"],   # +1
    ["red", "green", "blue"],   # +1
    ["red", "green", "blue"],   # +1
    ["pink", "brown", "black"],   # +2
    ["pink", "brown", "black"],   # +2
    ["pink", "brown", "black"],   # +2
    ["pink", "brown", "black"],   # +2
]
```

I cannot find any efficient approach to solve this problem.

- One solution can be to sort all list alphabetically and then find frequency of each list item in this whole list and then print list with max frequency.
- `from statistics import mode` also doesn't work here as this is list of list.

Comment: @Ch3steR Yeah, It can be. In that case, I want all modes and will concatenate in single list.

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` from the built-in `collections` module has a `most_common` method that could be used to find mode. Inner list order doesn't matter, so naturally, `set` is an option but since dictionary keys cannot be sets, `frozenset` can be used.

```py
from collections import Counter
list(Counter(map(frozenset, my_list)).most_common(1)[0][0])
# ['green', 'blue', 'red']
```

If you want all modes if there are many of them, you can use `multimode()` from `statistics` module.

```py
from statistics import multimode
list(map(list, multimode(map(frozenset, my_list))))
# [['green', 'blue', 'red'], ['brown', 'black', 'pink']]
```

All of these options convert the inner lists into frozensets, so any duplicate values will be lost. If you don't want that, you can sort the inner lists and call `multimode()`. Since the argument passed to `multimode()` has to be hashable, convert the sorted inner lists to tuples before passing to `multimode()`.

```py
[list(t) for t in multimode(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in my_list)]
```